# Windows Phone 8 Developer Registration Failure

Tags: windows-phone-8, device, registration

I have been struggling to get my test app work on an actual windows 8 phone.

I bought a nokia Lumia 920 recently and since has been trying to register my phone for app development.

I keep getting the error "Unable to connect to the phone. For Windows phone 8 phones make sure the Windows Phone IP over USB transport service is running" error. Have attached the screen shot.

I can confirm the following things.

1. The Windows Phone IP over USB transport service is running on my machine.
2. USB connection is fine, because as soon as I connect the phone gets listed under the devices list and i can browse the photos in phone.
3. Internet connection on both the phone and desktop on which phone is connected is working fine.
4. I am pretty sure I have developer licence because I have been developing apps for windows 8 appstore. If the license for my id is not enabled it could fail in the next steps. But at this moment the developer registration tool is not even identifying the device :(
5. I have switched off, date+time setting for "Set automatically"

Any help on this regard would be highly appreciated considering I have already spent 2-3 days trying the same thing and havent figured the solution yet. I bought this costly phone for developing apps and now struggling to get this up and running

Comment: I realized today that the phone needs to have a working internet connection as well for this to get through!

Answer (score 0):

For unlocking the phone for development there isn't really much to be done, just to connect the phone, have internet on it and register.

What could be the actual problem is the *Developer Account*. Windows Phone Store is not the same as Windows Store.

Personally, I've created accounts for both via University Agreements and the Microsoft Student Partner program so I haven't paid at all for them. First I made a developer account for Windows Phone, afterwards for Windows Store. But the point is, if I remember correctly, when I made the account for Windows 8 apps, it was detected that I already had one for phone and asked if I wanted them to get linked.

Summed up, I have a hunch that the problem is from the Dev Account. As far as I know, the Windows Phone Developer account is something totaly different that the Windows Store Developer Account.

Try with someone else's Windows Phone Microsoft Account that has the Windows Phone dev account attached to, or try with your own, but on a different machine with the Windows Phone SDK installed.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. But my hunch is, I am not even getting upto the screen where I could enter my account details. In short it appears the tool isnt detecting the phone.

Comment: Could be a corrupt software installation?... If you can, see if someone else can try to register his own phone but on your machine.

Comment: Yes. Finally I was able to give it a try again and this is what worked for me. 1. I was using the phone without a sim. I put the sim and the phone got registered. Now without sim too its working. Second, I had been trying on my Win 8 desktop and was unsuccessful. Could be a corrupt installation like you said. I used another Win 8 laptop to connect and now I am able to launch apps on the phone and debug. After all it appears to be a corrupt installation on my win 8 desktop but would like to figure out the root cause. Thanks @Vasile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Windows 8.1?

It seems - at least for Win8.1 - you need to install Windows Media Player. It seems to include the appropriate drivers for Windows Phone 8.